# Query Relationship in Laravel 9 User Registration

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Region` model that has a relationship with my `User` model.  I need a user to select which region they are in when registering. I'm getting an `Undefined variable $regions` error.

**RegisterUserController.php**

```
...
class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display the registration view.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
     */


    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'company_name' => ['required', 'string', 'unique:tenants,name'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ]);

        $tenant = Tenant::create([
            'name' => $request->company_name,
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'region_id' => $request->region_id,
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'role' => 'admin',
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'tenant_id' => $tenant->id,
        ]);

        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        event(new Registered($user));

        Auth::login($user);

        $regions = Region::all();

        return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME, compact('regions'));
    }
}
```

**register.blade**

```
...<!-- Region -->
<div class="mt-4">
    <select wire:model="region_id" id="region_id" name="region_id"
            class="block mt-1 w-full">
        <option>Choose Region</option>
        @foreach($regions as $reg)
            <option value="{{$reg->id}}">{{$reg->region_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
...
```

Comment: try to redirect route in this way:
`return redirect()->route('Route name')->with( ['regions ' => $regions ] );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to pass your regions from the controller action that renders the view instead:

```php
    public function create()
    {
        return view('auth.register', [
            'regions' => Region::all(),
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirect parameters are used to represent the parameters in the route URL

for example

```
// For a route with the following URI: profile/{id}
 
return redirect()->route('profile', ['id' => 1]);
```

for passing data at redirection you can use `with`

```
return \Redirect::route(RouteServiceProvider::HOME)->with(['regions'=>$regions]);
```

and in blade or controller you can access data using `session()->get('regions')`

```
...<!-- Region -->
<div class="mt-4">
    <select wire:model="region_id" id="region_id" name="region_id"
            class="block mt-1 w-full">
        <option>Choose Region</option>
       @if(session()->has('regions'))
          @foreach(session()->get('regions') as $reg)
            <option value="{{$reg->id}}">{{$reg->region_name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        @endif
        
    </select>
</div>
...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: I am getting a `foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given` error.

Comment: updated kindly check

Comment: The got rid of the error, but my Regions dropdown is empty.

Comment: I just realized, of course Regions is going to be be empty--I am trying to query it inside a save() function.  I moved it all the the create() function inside the same controller and it works.  Sorry for the run around.